# image blocking and subtraction of two images block-wise

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have two images: one is standard image and the other is reference image. I need to find the difference between the 1st block of the standard image with the first block of reference image and so on. The code I used for blocking is

```
S = imread ('standard image'); R = imread ('reference image');
% then converted images to grayscale images 

S = rgb2gray(S); R = rgb2gray (R);
% blocking of both images( as both images have 1600x2560 size) so i'm dividing 
it into 16 blocks of 4*4 matrix with block size of 400x640

div1= [400 400 400 400]; div2 = [640 640 640 640];
Bs = mat2cell (S, div1, div2); Br = mat2cell (R, div1,div2);
```

For viewing the blocks, I can use `imshow(Bs{1,1})` to `Bs{4,4}` OR simply by `imshow` `Br {1}` to `Br {16}`.

I need to find the difference by subtracting the blocks like first block of standard image and first block of reference image. I need to find a method to find index of each block and by applying loop on both images for subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
for i=1:length(div1), for j=1:length(div2), D{i,j}=abs(Bs{i,j}-Br{i,j}); end, end
```

Where D is de difference between both, or you can also rest the matrices before split them into blocks

```
D = abs(S-R);

div1= [400 400 400 400]; div2 = [640 640 640 640];
Bs = mat2cell (S, div1, div2); Br = mat2cell (R, div1,div2);
```

I have used `abs` because I dont know if you can have negative entries in a picture.

Comment: sir i am using for subtraction this Sub= cellfun(@minus,Br,Bs,'Un',0); and i need to start a loop that work on each cell and those  cells whose sub values are greater than zeros are shown and if all image has no single value are greater are called same images else differnt

Answer (score -1):

I would use something like:

```
I=double(S)-double(R)
surf(I)
view(2)
shading interp
axis tight
```

This lets me treat the intensities as a surface.

Comment: sir i am using for subtraction this Sub= cellfun(@minus,Br,Bs,'Un',0); and i need to start a loop that work on each cell and those cells whose sub values are greater than zeros are shown and if all image has no single value are greater are called same images else differnt